# wix toolset bootstrapper msipackage incorrect detect state

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I am creating vsto installer by wix toolset.

**Bundle.wxs**

```
<Chain>
  <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web" />
  <PackageGroupRef Id="PG_VSTORuntime" />
  <MsiPackage Id="SetupMSI"
              SourceFile="$(var.MsiPackageDir)\SetupMSI_MUI_$(var.Platform).msi"                  
              Permanent="no"
              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              Visible="yes" >
  </MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

**Unistall Log**

```
Detected package: NetFx40Web, state: Present, cached: None
Detected package: EP_VSTORuntime, state: Present, cached: None
Detected package: SetupMSI_MUI_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
```

**SetupMSI_MUI_x86** is incorrect State Absent Even though msipackage is installed.

msipackage itself works fine.

What should I check?

Comment: If you didn't use a static GUID for the Id of your MSI `Product` and have rebuilt your MSI since having installed it on the machine, it will not detect that product as installed. This is almost certainly working properly.

Comment: checking [morphing-installer](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/transforms/morphing-installers) 
It was small bootstrapper.  thanks brian.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue, but the product ID for my MSI is static.
The package is never detected.

If I run the EXE after install, and select Uninstall, only the bootstrapper is removed.

I have to run the EXE again, which runs my MSI, which then allows me to uninstall the MSI package.